# Reducing the thickness of a layer of elemental sulfur

Tags: experimental-chemistry, materials

I want to make a very thin film of elemental sulfur. While mechanical polishing can bring a film to 10 microns in thickness, but I need to bring my thickness lower (hundreds of nanometers). Although I searched, I was unsuccessful in finding any methods for chemical etching elemental sulfur.

Are there any methods for reducing the thickness of elemental sulfur below 10 microns, preferably to lengths on the order of hundreds of nanometers?

Comment: Rather than trying to make a thick layer thinner, how about vacuum deposition of sulfur? In other words, just make a thin layer.

Comment: As @MaxW states, vacuum (or vapor) deposition is the way to go. I've produced layers of gold just a few atoms thick, so thin that they are completely transparent or a clear, pale, green, that way.

Comment: I don't have access to vapor deposition type coating systems for this process, so I was hoping to find some way to do this in a chemical etch method.